# How to insert values using AJAX in Laravel?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to build a simple notifications system but only using a boolean type of read notification. I want to send a request / values of **"1"** or **"True"** when users **on click** the a href tag. But the AJAX seems not sending any values, what's to be the problem? Thankyou.

> Route

```html
Route::controller(TaskController::class)->prefix('dashboard/task')->middleware(['role:admin|operator|user-bisnis|user-qa'])->group(function () {
    Route::get('/', 'index');
    Route::get('/create', 'create')->name('task.create');
    Route::post('/', 'store')->name('task.store');
    Route::get('/edit/{id}', 'edit')->name('task.edit');
    Route::post('/update/{id}', 'update')->name('task.update');
    Route::post('/delete/{id}', 'destroy')->name('task.delete');
    Route::post('/readnotif', 'readnotif')->name('task.read');
});
```

> Controller

```html
public function readnotif(Dokumentasi $dokumentasi, Request $request, $id)
    {
        $rules = [
            "read" => 1
        ];

        $dokumentasi = $dokumentasi->where('id', $id)->update($rules);
    }
```

> Blade

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#readnotif').on('click', function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: "{{ route('task.read') }}",
            dataType: 'json',
            type: "POST",
            cache: false,
            data: {
                "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}"
                "read": '1',
            }
            // success: function(response) {

            //     //...

            // },
            // error: function(error) {

            //     //...

            // }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

```html
<a class="dropdown-item d-flex align-items-center" href="{{ route('task.edit', Crypt::encrypt($dokumentasi->id)) }}" id="readnotif">
```

Comment: "But the AJAX seems not sending any values" - how did you check that? It should be pretty simple to validate whether the request **really** sends the values by inspecting the request in your browser's network console

Comment: Do you **prevent** the **default** behaviour of your link when clicking it?

Comment: i just want to know how to send values using ajax

Comment: @brombeer as far i know, im not. but how to check these ?

Comment: @brombeer yes it end up on the 'task.edit', but i wanted to send values also at the same time, the DevConsole not showing anything

Comment: "i just want to know how to send values using ajax" - so, this problem isn't related to PHP after all? Then please remove the irrelevant parts, and share more details about your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: @NicoHaase which part is irrelevant ? i'm using Laravel framework ?

Comment: If **sending** values using AJAX is relevant, this does not involve Laravel after all, as AJAX is running in the browser, and **sending** values from your browser is a pure JS task

Comment: Use a `<button type="button"...` instead of a link (or use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) to test your AJAX. Once you click that link you'll be taken to a fresh page, so you don't have access to any console output from your ajax any more.

Comment: Your Route 'task.read' is missing the param $id. Update to: Route::post('/readnotif/{value}', 'readnotif')->name('task.read'); or use the value as a query string like: ?id=notif_id and replace the href to a # (to avoid misunderstanding)